# conda install python didn't change python version

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to updgrade my anaconda3-installed python version from 3.6.15 to 3.10. I tried `conda install python=3.10` and although it took 45hrs to resolve conflicts, it seemed to complete the process. However when I type `python --version` it appears it's still on `3.6.15`. Am I missing something fundamental here? How do I get my version onto 3.10?

Comment: are you trying change the python version in the base environment? Because I dont think thats possible

Comment: I was, yes. I'd seen a lot of people mentioning that you 'can' create a new environment, but none of them really impressed upon me that you __should__ do so. I'm just not going to bother with the base environment anymore.

Comment: You should definitely not be using your base environment like that.

Comment: I am running into similar issue. In fact, I ended up recreating the environment with python version 3.11.5 and now the conda config shows python version as 3.11.4 but the python version at the command line is 3.11.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, upgrading the version of Python in an environment is a bit tricky. As you found, there are a lot of dependencies to figure out, especially with a big step like 3.6 to 3.10.

Rather than upgrading Python from 3.6 to 3.10 in a given environment, the easiest thing to do is probably to create a new environment.

This should work:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.10
```

This creates a new environment called `myenv` (or whatever you want), which is running Python 3.10. Once it has finished (it should be *much* less than 45 hours!), you can do this:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Now you can do install new libraries, do your work, etc, in Python 3.10. You can nuke the other environment (`conda env remove`) or keep it in case you need it.

If you're asking about changing your `base` environment, my advice is to ignore that environment and use your own environments for everything.

If you're asking about changing the *default* Python version for your Anaconda, I think you have to upgrade Anaconda. To be honest, if your Anaconda is that old, I would probably do that anyway. My approach is just to blow `~/Anaconda3` away and re-install it from scratch, but maybe there's a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Creating a new environment was SO MUCH easier. I thought it would be easier to just have one base environment, as I never find myself having to switch versions, I'm just doing it now for the hell of it... but this was so much easier. I am finding there's some packages I was expecting would be included, like ipykernel and pandas... but so far I've been able to address it by either installing/force-reinstalling the 'missing' packages.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I think it's worth getting used to environments. At some point you'll need some old or new version of Python (or some library) that you don't want to switch everything to.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely going to stick with individual environments now. I don't know how often I'll have to switch between them, but I see now how straightforward it actually is to use them.